# Find the best match in two lists of preferences

Tags: python

Given the preference of cafe in order , find the best match for both the friends.

- Friend1 - [1 ,2 ,3]
- Friend2 - [3 ,1 ,4]

where 1-> cafe1, 2->cafe2 and so on

I tried working it finding the least difference in the indices which match. But it fails on [1,2,3][2,4,3]

```
def find_match(f1,f2):

    difference=len(f1)

    for i in range(len(f1)):
        for j in range(len(f2)):
            if f1[i]==f2[j]:
                curr_diff=abs(i-j)
                if curr_diff<difference:
                    difference=curr_diff
                    print(f1[i])
                    return
```

For

```
 Friend1 - [1 ,2 ,3] 
 Friend2 - [3 ,1 ,4]
```

the output should be 1

For [1,2,3],[2,4,3] output should be 2

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more how you expect this to work? For example, for [1,2,3],[3,2,1] what should the output be?

Comment: @UnsolvedCypher, as I understood, output should be 2

Comment: *Why* should the output be `2` in that case.  You look for the best-match position, and `3` is in the same position in both lists, just as you described with your code.

Comment: Also, please include the results of the debugging attempts you've made.  "Here's my code, the output is wrong" is too high-level to be useful to most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat the order as a "weight" for each cafe.  This would be easy to manage in a dictionary.

```
friend1 = ["A","B","C"]
friend2 = ["C","A","D"]
votes = dict()
friends = [friend1,friend2]
for preferences in friends:
    for weigth,cafe in enumerate(preferences):
        votes[cafe] = votes.get(cafe,0) + weigth
_,bestCafe = min((v,k) for k,v in votes.items())
print(bestCafe) # A
```

*Note I used letters for the cafes to avoid confusion with indexes.  The lowest weight corresponds to the prefered cafe*

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if this is what you're looking for, and `i + 1` seems strange, but it returns the correct result for your specification

```
def best_cafe(l1, l2):
    match = []
    for i, item in enumerate(l1):
        if item not in l2:
            continue
        match.append(i + 1)

    return min(match)


l3 = [1, 2, 3]
l4 = [3, 1, 4]

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [2, 4, 3]

print best_cafe(l3, l4)
print best_cafe(l1, l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about one-liner?

```
f1 = [1, 2, 3] 
f2 = [3, 1, 4]

best = min(((i1 + 1) * (i2 + 1), v1) for i1, v1 in enumerate(f1) for i2, v2 in enumerate(f2) if v1 == v2)[1]
```